# magento entity value can not be null

Tags: php, magento, email

when i write below code

```
$email=$recipient['email'];
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
->loadByEmail($email);
```

i get error entity value can be null why so what should i write there

what should i write to make it work, i had already set share customer to global but still same error message

Comment: Actually what you want trying to do ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$email=$recipient['email'];
$customer = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')
->setWebsiteId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getWebsiteId())
->loadByEmail($email);
```

you have to make it global then it will work